# bar graph with log Y-axis

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, scale, point

I have a dataframe:
`tibble [56 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)`
`$ Species    : Factor w/ 56 levels "OC1","OC2","OC3",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...`
`$ Residential: num [1:56] 0 0.077 0.0997 0.1023 0.2268 ...`
`$ FW_AVG     : num [1:56] 0.022 0.0944 0.1121 0.0641 0.0659 ...`

I need to plot a bar graph showing Species on X-axis and FW_AVG on Y-axis as bar graph and Residential values on Y-axis as scatter or visa-versa. However I am trying to plot the bar-graph but i am getting the bar direction from upside-down.

`ggplot(data, aes(x = Species, y = FW_AVG)) +`
`geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue", position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +`
`scale_y_log10() +`
`labs(x = "Species", y = "FW_AVG (log scale)") +`
`theme_minimal() +`
`theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))'`

and the graph is (the one with bluecoloured bar graph) [image]

however I need the graph as reference graph

[image]

can anyone help me in finding the error in my code please.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the problem is that `ggplot` is technically correct in how it plots your numbers. As 10^0 = 1, your highest values of 1 are now technically 0s on a plot, and the values below 1 are negative numbers (10 to the power of a negative number). The graph you want to reproduce 'cheats' by adding a bottom line at an arbitrary point.

This cheat is reproducible in R. Use `scales::pseudo_log_trans()` to make it look like a log scale:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

data <- tibble(Species = letters,
               FW_AVG = (runif(26)) ^ 4)


ggplot(data, aes(x = Species, y = FW_AVG)) + geom_bar(
  stat = "identity",
  fill = "steelblue",
  position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)
) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 10^-3, base = 10),
    breaks = 10 ^ -seq(3, 0),
    labels = label_scientific()
  ) +
  labs(x = "Species", y = "FW_AVG (log scale)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]